# How can I optimize the Microsoft AJAX Toolkit?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

This is rather infuriating.  I'm trying to optimize a very large site, and I'm at the step of reducing HTTP Requests.  Microsoft is not cooperating.  I have the following ScriptResources included.  I'll try and grab a top-line for each to distinguish them

1. // Name:        MicrosoftAjax.debug.js  53.5Kb
2. // Name:        MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.debug.js  14Kb
3. AjaxControlToolkit.BoxSide = function() {  11.4Kb
4. /// Sys.UI.DomElement   **958 Bytes!**
5. // Sys.Timer   **982 Bytes!**
6. // IDropSource  6.5Kb
7. AjaxControlToolkit.FloatingBehavior = function(element) { 2.2Kb
8. AjaxControlToolkit.BehaviorBase = function(element) {  5.4Kb
9. AjaxControlToolkit.DynamicPopulateBehavior = function(element) { 2.9Kb
10. AjaxControlToolkit.BoxCorners = function() { 3.6Kb
11. AjaxControlToolkit.DropShadowBehavior = function(element) { 3.4Kb
12. AjaxControlToolkit.ModalPopupBehavior = function(element) { 5.5Kb

**Come on!**  12 Bloody javascript includes!  Less than a KILOBYTE!  Half the time to get the dang data is probably spent asking for it!  ARGHHH!

Anyway, as you can see, I am annoyed.  Is there some way I can roll these up, and combine them?  Like into *one* request?

Comment: What do you mean, "probably"? Surely you've measured how much time is spent waiting for this data? Otherwise you're wasting your time trying to optimize. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Just replace `<asp:ScriptManager ... />`
>   with `<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager> ... />`
>   in your ASPX page and you're
>   done!

http://blogs.msdn.com/delay/archive/2007/06/11/script-combining-made-easy-overview-of-the-ajax-control-toolkit-s-toolkitscriptmanager.aspx

Answer (score 3):

You can write a HTTPModule to grab all the the axd/js files from the response, combine them into one, and send them to the client's browser through a request to an HTTPHandler.

You can take a look at [Mads Kristensen's](http://madskristensen.net/post/Compress-WebResourceaxd-in-ASPNET.aspx) site to know what I am talking about. There are a lot many articles/workarounds for problems like yours.

Answer (score 1):

check this:

[Fast ASP.NET web page loading by downloading multiple javascripts in batch](http://weblogs.asp.net/omarzabir/archive/2008/05/10/fast-asp-net-web-page-loading-by-downloading-multiple-javascripts-in-batch.aspx)

Also, one common mistake is setting `<compilation debug=”true”/>` in some of the sites I have seen. As per [Scott Gu](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/11/Don_1920_t-run-production-ASP.NET-Applications-with-debug_3D001D20_true_1D20_-enabled.aspx),

*When `<compilation debug=”false”/>` is set, the WebResource.axd handler will automatically set a long cache policy on resources retrieved via it – so that the resource is only downloaded once to the client and cached there forever (it will also be cached on any intermediate proxy servers).*

Answer (score 0):

The question is how to minimize the overall requests to your server....

personally, i think its not a problem, if these js files are loaded ONCE.
because they should be cached by the client. maybe you want to investigate, why this does not happen.
and secondly there is a tag at the ScriptManager, that limits your js files....
maybe you want to look into the CompositeScript tag...

addditionally i would suggest looking into the LoadScriptsBevoreUI attribute and set it to false. then your content gets loaded bevore the javascripts.

Comment: It can be a real PITA once you actually run into it. Consider a Web Application that's primarily used by people on the road with 3G Datacards. Latency & Handsake time is crap with these cards. And browsers only support 2 concurrent requests, so this kind of rubbish can massively reduce the "speed" of a page download under certain conditions

Comment: first download. first handshake. yes.
afterwards you can avoid checks on the server, if you set the files expiry date to a year, and add your version number to the file name.
new version ->  new url.

Answer (score 0):

Use CombineScripts=true inside your ToolkitScriptManager